# The Difference Between "I just love you" and "I love you"

Tags: meaning, verbs, word-usage

What is the difference between "I 'just' love you" and "I love you"?

Comment: First in a song by Tim McGraw and second is another by Beatles!!! 

It seems the first expression is used for showing emphasis.

Comment: Context will be very important with this one. *Love* is such a delicate concept wherever it's used that, without information including (but certainly not limited to) inflection, character backgroun, situation.. This one would be hard to answer accurately.

Comment: I'm having a hard time coming up with a context where "I just love you" makes any sense. Where did you hear/see this? Please edit your question to include more details.

Comment: "I just love you... Any less and I would be apathetic towards you" would be one context. '"I just love you," he cried, desperate that she took it as not enough of a reason for him to act so' might be a context for an alternative interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

> I, I just love you
>   Don't know why I just do
>   When are you coming home?
>   Babe I'm coming home soon
>   And I just love you too

*I just love you* in this context means that the speaker loves without any motive, reason or cause.

Like if we say something *just disappeared*, then it disappeared without apparent cause. It disappeared - and that is all.

Answer (score 1):

I think that "I just love you" implies nothing else matters or could get in the way, in terms of this love. Maybe a sense that everything else is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Until more context is provided I would parse

> I *just* love ***you***.

to mean the same as this sentence:

> I love *just **you***.

Where "just you" is the direct object, in other words, ***you*** are the **only** one I love.

[image]
<sub>[Syddansk Universitet: Visual Interactive Syntax Learning](http://beta.visl.sdu.dk/visl/en/parsing/automatic/trees.php)</sub>

So the difference is: "I love you" is non-exclusive (a mother might say that to each of her children), whereas "I *just* love ***you***"["I love ***just you***"] is exclusive (a young woman might say that to reassure her jealous boyfriend)... clearly there are different relationships where the word "love" is used.

Answer (score 0):

"I just love you" = "I really love you" (can also be interpreted as "I love you very much") - usually said with emotion.

But, "I just like you" would have a different meaning, not in the same sense as above, as anyone can see.

"I love you" is a simple declaration.